# Exit process when pipe finish

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to import users from a CSV file with node.js in CLI.

But I don't know how to exit program properly when all the tasks are completed.

Here my code using [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.com/) and [node-csv](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv)

```
"use strict";

const Sails    = require('sails');    
const fs       = require('fs');
const csv      = require('csv');
const filename = './test.csv';

Sails.load({
  models : { migrate : 'safe'},
  log    : { level : 'info' },
  hooks  : { grunt : false, sockets : false, pubsub : false },
}, (errSails, sails) => {

  if ( errSails ) process.exit(1);

  let input = fs.createReadStream(filename);
  let parser = csv.parse();
  let transformer = csv.transform( (record) => {
    sails.log.debug('record : ', record);
    sails.log.info('Transformer : searching user...');
    return User.findOne({email: record.email})
    .then( (user) => {
      sails.log.info('Transformer : search complete');
      if ( !user ) {
        sails.log.info('Transformer : no users found');
        return User.create(record);
      }
      return record;
    })
    .catch( (err) =>  sails.log.error(err) );
  });

  parser
  .on('readable', () => sails.log.info('Parser readable'))
  .on('finish', () => sails.log.info('Parser finish'))
  .on('error', (err) => sails.log.error('Parser error : ', err));

  transformer
  .on('finish', () => sails.log.info('Transformer finish'))
  .on('error', (err) => sails.log.error('Transformer error : ', err));

  input.pipe(parser).pipe(transformer).pipe(process.stdout);

  //--- Exit program
  // process.exit();
});
```

Here is what is inside the terminal

```
debug: record : { ... }
info: Transformer : searching user...
info: Parser readable
info: Parser finish
info: Transformer finish
info: Transformer : search complete
info: Transformer : no users found
```

Without `process.exit();`, the program continue forever.

If I uncomment the `process.exit();` line, the program terminate immediately without parsing anything. But, if I put this line into the finish event of the transformer, the program exit after `info: Transformer finish` without the last two lines.

I want to know how and where I should put `process.exit();` to exit program to be sure that all users of my CSV file are created in the database.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't try to user Process exit on error happening, use throws new Error. read more [here](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/02/04/maintainable-node-js-javascript-avoid-process-exit/).
and about your problem:  the second thing you have an async function and put your exit program command out of async function body, so it makes your second problem, for your first problem, to make exit when everything will be done, you should change your async function first.to something like this:

```
  .on('finish', () => {sails.log.info('Transformer finish');process.exit(1);})
```

Comment: This is a demo code. It just shows logs to understand what's happening. Of course my code throws errors on `error` events. And I said that if I put the `process.exit(1);` into the `finish` event, the code stops even if the transformer have not finish async treatment.

Comment: I see, your code quite good. Did you try add a process.exits on your finish event ?

Comment: yes that's what I did but if I do, everything in `User.findOne({email: record.email}).then( (user) => {/*here*/});` is not executed because Transformer's `finish` event is called before async treatment in`csv.transform()` is done.

Comment: and what about end event?
can finde more detail about this two event at this link 
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_events_finish_and_end